# Cloud Integration of appengine app is stuck at error. AppIdentity says "app is invalid". How can I unstick it?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an AppEngine app that was created just before the whole revolution of service accounts et al, and now I want to give it a service account. Unfortunately, the migration step seems to fail with `An error occurred when creating the project. Please retry.`

[image: From the dashboard]

When I try to log the service account from the AppIdentity api, I get
`com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceFailureException: The application is not valid.`

The app id is `pd-production-statbot`. Can anyone suggest a way to get my app out of its rut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from Google support is that my app got stuck in some weird in-between state. They offered to fix it for me manually, or I can wait until it gets caught by a cleanup process. Without a Google support contact, I think the only workaround is to make a new appengine app altogether and transfer your data to it.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. I had the same problem, and after contacting the Google Cloud support (https://console.cloud.google.com/support), they fixed it for me.